# HTML5 Canvas image resize without quality loss

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am drawing an image to a canvas to allow the user to paint some lines on it and save the result. For mobile users, the canvas has a maximum `clientWidth` and `cliendHeight` and the image is scaled down to fit the canvas. Everything works perfectly, except that the quality of the canvas image is not good enough. Is there a way to preserve the resolution of the original image and also the drawing on the image?

My code currently supports rotation and the main part is as follows -

```
if (rotateAngle == 0 || rotateAngle == 180) {
    scale = Math.min(clientWidth / img.width, clientHeight / img.height);
    height = Math.ceil(img.height * scale);
    width = Math.ceil(img.width * scale);
}
else if (rotateAngle == 90 || rotateAngle == 270) {
    scale = Math.min(clientWidth / img.height, clientHeight / img.width);
    height = Math.ceil(img.width * scale);
    width = Math.ceil(img.height * scale);
}

canvas.height = height;
canvas.width = width;
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2);
ctx.rotate(rotateAngle*Math.PI/180);
if (rotateAngle == 90 || rotateAngle == 270) {
    ctx.drawImage(img, -canvas.height/2, -canvas.width/2, canvas.height, canvas.width);
}
else{
    ctx.drawImage(img, -canvas.width/2, -canvas.height/2, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
ctx.restore();
```

Currently I am planning to store the entire line drawing as points and then reapplying it on another canvas with full sized image. I don't know much about point/canvas scaling like this so any help would be appreciated

Comment: `canvas.height = height * 2; 
canvas.width = width * 2;` ?

Comment: @Berto99 Sorry I don't understand what this will do

Comment: `canvas` has 2 width, one is `canvas.width` that is the width of the context where you draw, and `canvas.style.width` that is the width of the DOM element... if you force `canvas.style.width = x` and you set `canvas.width = x * 2` than you will have double the resolution on the context, in the same "DOM space", so it will appear more defined

Comment: That makes sense! Let me try

Comment: ok let me know if it worked out

Comment: @Berto99 I had to scale the mouse coordinates according to the scale_factor, and it worked! Thanks a lot!!